# Problems with the [DataType] Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, annotations, data-annotations

**This is my code in the Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The url is required")]
[Url(ErrorMessage = "Invalid URL")]
public String Url { get; set; }
```

**This is my code in the view:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Feed URL" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Url)
</div>*emphasized text*
```

The problem is that the *Url annotation*, should render an input with an attribute *type="url"*

**This is what i get:**

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The url is required" data-val-url="Invalid URL" id="Url" name="Url" placeholder="Feed URL" type="text" value="">
```

**This is what i should get:**

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The url is required" data-val-url="Invalid URL" id="Url" name="Url" placeholder="Feed URL" type="url" value="">
```

*The type of the first is "text", and for the input that I should get is "url".*

Comment: Are you sure you're using MVC 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manually set the type i.e

new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Feed URL", **type="url"** }

because you are using the Html.TextBoxFor, it will render the type as text.

you could always use Html.EditorFor and then create your own editor template "url" and pass the required html attributes in the viewdata.

Comment: Oh that was useful! I'm really thanked. Now i think I'm going to put the type in in the anonymous object. What do you think is more common, the EditorFor or TextBoxFor ?

Comment: glad i could help! i personally prefer using TextBoxFor for this situation, because i can easily specify html attributes. I generally use EditorFor for more complex situations where i need to use custom EditorTemplates